# Post data to an API in Form Data type in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I want to POST the data in the form of "Form data" type, instead of query string. The code I used:

```
angular.module('odeskApp') 
 .factory('Password', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        update: function (pwd) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                url: 'http://example.com/api/user/password',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $.param({ 
     'password': pwd 
    }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                    }
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $('#changePasswordAlert').html('<div class="alert alert-success"><b>Successfully Done!</b> Change password process completed.</div>');
     $('#changePasswordAlert .alert').mouseout(function(){ $(this).fadeOut('slow'); });
                    deferred.resolve(data); //resolve data
               })
                .error(function (err) { 
     $('#changePasswordAlert').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><b>Failed!</b> Change password process failed.</div>');
     deferred.reject();
     $('#changePasswordAlert .alert').mouseout(function(){ $(this).fadeOut('slow'); });
    });
            return deferred.promise; 
        }
    };
});
```

Any possible help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to call is you use the simple $http.post:

```
$http.post(url, {'password': pwd}, configs)
.then(sucessFunc, failFunc);
```

I abstracted the full example, to make it clean. if you want i can put the full code.

Edit: Full example

```
angular.module('odeskApp') 
 .factory('Password', function ($http) {
    var url = 'http://example.com/api/user/password';
    // you can remove the configs if they are not needed...
    var configs = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      }
    };
    return {
        update: function (pwd) {
          $http.post(url, {'password': pwd}, configs)
            .then(function (data){ return data; });
        }
    };
});
```

This should work fine. i didn't add the Refect on fail because it will automaticly send reject to the queue of promises.
Also $http return promises so no need to use $q. 
Html manipulation should not be used in a factory. that is why i removed it from my example. See some guides on angular docs. 
Basicly you should have a template, that use a controller, that call this service, then use $scopes to talk messages between controller and views.
Hope this get you going.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I was dragging my head from long time.

I tried kind of similar code but dint get it working. If possible please post the full code.

Comment: Checkout this article http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm